# Using LinkedIn's REST API with Play! 2 and Oauth 2

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, playframework-2.0, linkedin-api

We want to update our user profiles with information from LinkedIn (should the user choose to import this information). However, we want to this this authorization using Oauth2, but accordoing to LinkedIn's website only Ouath 1.0a is supported for their REST API: https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LinkedIn is providing OAuth 2 access using their [JavaScript API](https://developer.linkedin.com/javascript) you could dive into their Javascript code and somehow get to the file, that has [the OAuth 2 endpoints](https://platform.linkedin.com/js/secureAnonymousFramework?v=0.0.2000-RC1.20001-1400) in it:

```
l.api = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1";
l.login = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/connect/user-signin";
l.authorize = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorize?immediate=true";
[...]
l.logout = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/connect/logout?oauth_token={OAUTH_TOKEN}&api_key={API_KEY}&callback={CALLBACK}";
l.userspace_renew = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/js/authuserspace?v=0.0.2000-RC1.20001-1400&api_key={API_KEY}";
```

For requesting resources, probably the endpoints in their [REST API documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-api-resource-map) could be used.

However, note that it is probably forbidden by their [terms of use](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use) to use these endpoints without their JS API and could result in your client being sanctionized. You could contact them and ask for permission.

Comment: Thanks! I think we might just end up using SecureSocial though: https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Play 2.x client in Scala and Java which supports OAuth/CAS/OpenID/HTTP authentication and user profile retrieval : https://github.com/leleuj/play-pac4j.

For OAuth support, it's based on Scribe and supports LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo, DropBox, Github, Windows live, WordPress...